# "header not found" as I import public header from private header

Tags: objective-c, module, frameworks, clang, dynamic-library

I am developing a `dynamic framework` in `Objective-C` that has public and private headers.
Due to some reasons, I do **NOT** use modular import directives

(e.g: `#import <MyFramework/MyPublicHeader.h>`)

instead, I use non-modular import directives

(e.g: `#import "MyPublicHeader.h"`)

and I still can build a module so that I can import them from my framework module

(e.g: `#import <MyFramework/MyPublicHeader.h>`)

So far so good. But, when I import a public header from inside of a private header, I get "header not found" compiler errors.

### Example

#### MyPrivateHeader.h: (compiler error!)

```
#import "MyPublicHeader.h"
```

#### MyPrivateHeader.h: (NO compiler error!)

```
#import <MyFramework/MyPublicHeader.h>
```

I checked other projects (for example `YAPDatabase`) and it imports public headers from its private headers without error. In fact, I already solved the problem for now but I still would like to learn more about the internals of this process. Why do I get "header not found" in this case?

Can anyone illuminate me about the internal mechanism of `modules`, `public headers` and `private headers`?

Comment: Hi Mert, I've run into the same obstacle - have you found out what's going on with this?

Comment: as i said in the question, if you do `#import <MyFramework/MyPublicHeader.h>` compiler does compile. yet, i still don't know the real reason of "header not found" problem. hope that helps

Comment: Same problem here. I will do the same change that guys did. Thanks. (Upvoted)